Is it possible to cache data when cloning a git repo?
I am working with a very unstable connection and I am trying to clone a very large repo. I often get errors like:
error: RPC failed; curl 18 Transferred a partial file3.00 KiB/s 
error: 19112 bytes of body are still expected

or
error: RPC failed; curl 18 HTTP/2 stream 5 was reset22.00 KiB/s 
error: 5630 bytes of body are still expected

or the connection is just dropping.
Is there any way to run with some sort of caching feature when cloning? So to not start from scratch every single time.

You could ask to clone by providing a published commit ID so that you fetch more (later, also published) commits (also providing their IDs) a little bit at a time.... A pain in the back side but it's technically possible.

It's a good idea indeed. It can be painful since the project is quite large: 140k commits are a bit.

@Limone Do you really need all these commits and files in them? If not — you can do shallow clone (only a few commits) and partial clone (not all files).

I didn't know about the shallow clones. It's a great suggestion indeed!
